# Python exchangelib OAuth2 authentication failing

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, exchangewebservices, exchangelib

Since Microsoft has apparently EOL'd basic authentication for Exchange Web Services, I'm trying to convert my Python app to use OAuth2. Python 3.8, exchangelib 3.2.1, ms-exchange version unknown but recent. Relevant code follows:

```
from exchangelib import Credentials, Account, Message, Mailbox, ExtendedProperty, Configuration, \
                        OAuth2Credentials, OAuth2AuthorizationCodeCredentials, Identity, OAUTH2
from oauthlib.oauth2 import OAuth2Token

    credentials = OAuth2Credentials(client_id="xxxxxxxx-xxxx-etc", client_secret="xxxxxxxxxxxxx-etc",
                                    tenant_id="xxxxxxxx-xxxx-etc")
    config=Configuration(credentials=credentials, auth_type=OAUTH2)
    acct = Account(primary_smtp_address='testAddr@example.com', config=config, autodiscover=True)
```

The result:

```
ValueError: Auth type must be 'OAuth 2.0' for credentials type OAuth2Credentials
DEBUG:exchangelib.protocol:Server autodiscover.example.com: Closing sessions
```

The exception is being thrown at the beginning of BaseProtocol.create_oauth2_session() in protocol.py:

```
        if self.auth_type != OAUTH2:
            raise ValueError('Auth type must be %r for credentials type OAuth2Credentials' % OAUTH2)
```

Straightforward enough...except that I clearly specified auth_type=OAUTH2 in my code. Eventually I discovered that a second Configuration object is being created; the first with type OAUTH2 as expected, the second with type NTLM, and that's the one that create_oauth2_session is failing on. The second instance is carrying my credentials, but the service endpoint argument changes from None to autodiscover.example.com/Autodiscover/Autodiscover.xml. This makes sense as part of the autodiscover process (I think,) but why the second instance, and why is it changing the auth type?? I'm stumped. Any/all help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a bug. [This commit](https://github.com/ecederstrand/exchangelib/commit/bb547ae55646e281ac8069791ffe0e2eef3d68b5) should have allowed OAuth for autodiscover but it apparently doesn't work for you. I would break out a debugger and find out where the `auth_type` value is getting reset. I don't have an OAuth-enabled EWS server, so I can't test this myself.